# What is the meaning of "sword and gun on the table"

Tags: meaning

This phrase is used in The Sopranos by Phil Leotardo:

> Listen to me. They make anybody and everybody over there. And the way that they do it, it's all f***ed up. Guys don't get their finger pricked. There's no sword and gun on the table...

Comment: At a guess the speaker is complaining that the mob 'over there' doesn't have any ceremonal induction when a mobster is made a "man of honor" (mafioso).

Comment: It took me a while to understand ***make*** here (originally I thought it might be "detect", as in identifying "spies" from rival gangs). But I'm sure in the context of the actual movie / TV episode it would have been obvious it's something like ***make** [some up-and-coming young thug] a **member** of the local street gang*. But I'm guessing that context should also make it obvious that "sword & gun" means "ritual paraphernalia".

Comment: In Italian-American crime-family jargon, a "made man" is someone who has been formally inducted into the Mafia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sword and the gun are part of the ritual of joining the Mafia although it appears that some clans use a knife:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiation_ritual_(mafia)

> **In Sicily:**
>
> an aspiring member must take part in an initiation ritual [...]. he
> describes the initiation ritual he underwent in the spring of 1893:
>
> I was invited to take part in a secret meeting of the Fratuzzi. I entered a mysterious room where there were many men armed with guns
> sitting around a table. In the center of the table there was a skull
> drawn on a piece of paper and a knife. To be admitted to the Fratuzzi,
> I had to undergo an initiation consisting of some trials of loyalty
> and the pricking of the lower lip with the tip of the knife: the blood
> from the wound soaked the skull
>
> **In the United States**
>
> Valachi gave the most well-known description of the ceremony:
>
> I sit down at the table. There is wine. Someone put a gun and a knife in front of me. The gun was a .38 and the knife was what we call
> a dagger. Maranzano [the boss] motions us up and we say some words in
> Italian. Then Joe Bonanno pricks my finger with a pin and squeezes
> until the blood comes out. What then happens, Mr. Maranzano says,
> 'This blood means that we are now one Family. You live by the gun and
> the knife and you die by the gun and the knife.'